# Invalid header ???Manifest-Version during ant read my manifest

Tags: manifest

my Manifest.mf's code set is UTF-8.
During ant task is trying to read it, throw "invalid header ???Manifest-Version".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other Manifests work fine, but their code set is ANSI.
So I convert my manifest to be ANSI. It works fine.
Maybe ant task only works with ANSI instead of UTF-8....